# Networking with devices in local network

Tags: networking

I have a local home network (my router) I have a raspberry pi setup as a web server. I do not want the web server to be access from devices outside my home network. I only want local devices to connect to the web server. I belief I am able to do this like (raspberrypi.local). Do I have to port forward on the router for local devices to connect to the pi or is port forwarding used for external devices outside the network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port forwarding is used to access internal network ports from outside.